# Getting error message "Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6."

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying google analytic in my project. but found following error message after changing build.gradle file.

Error:Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/home/vaibhav/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/2.0.0-alpha6/google-services-2.0.0-alpha6.pom
    file:/home/vaibhav/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/2.0.0-alpha6/google-services-2.0.0-alpha6.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/2.0.0-alpha6/google-services-2.0.0-alpha6.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/2.0.0-alpha6/google-services-2.0.0-alpha6.jar
Required by:
    :MaterialTabs-master:unspecified

where I 
1. Add the dependency to your project-level build.gradle:

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'

2.Add the plugin to your app-level build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

and

3. add a dependency for Google Play Services. Inside build.gradle add:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem as you did, and having looked at [Google Analytics Quickstart project](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/analytics) linked by [Tiem Song's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641170/5011576) the I think you are missing the `jcenter()` repository as I was.

JCenter is the now the default repository used with Android’s gradle plugin[0], but older projects were created using `mavenCentral()` as the default repository, which doesn't have any of the google-services.

Your `build.gradle` should look like.

```
repositories {
    ...
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta6'
}
```

(I have also updated the beta version from 5 to 6, but that is just to make the answer as current as possible)

Hope that helps

[0] - http://blog.bintray.com/2015/02/09/android-studio-migration-from-maven-central-to-jcenter/

Answer (score 0):

Give the `beta5` versions of the dependencies a try:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta5'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta5'
```

The [Google Analytics Quickstart project](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/analytics) is a working Android app and includes `build.gradle` examples.