# can't build android project it shows error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

project gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.arun4fms.efix"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.chabbal:slidingdotsplash:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'webapp'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha3/gradle-3.0.0-alpha3.pom
>            file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha3/gradle-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha3/gradle-3.0.0-alpha3.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha3/gradle-3.0.0-alpha3.jar
>        Required by:
>            project :

Comment: Update your build tools from SDK manager

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601704/getting-error-message-could-not-find-com-google-gmsgoogle-services2-0-0-alpha

Answer (score 16):

As already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44071080/1009132):

> Google have new maven repo, so it could be the reason.
>
> https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-studio-3-0-canary1.html
>
> > section **Google's Maven Repository**
>
> https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Add Google’s Maven Repository to the buildscript repositories section to fix it like @KG87 did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44406647/1009132).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } // Add this line to fix it
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'
        ...
    }
}
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13923766/1009132):

> The repositories in the buildScript block are used to fetch the
>   dependencies of your buildScript dependencies. These are the
>   dependencies that are put on the classpath of your build and that you
>   can refer to from your build file. For instance, extra plugins that
>   exist on the internet.
>
> The repositories on the root level are used to fetch the dependencies
>   that your project depends on. So all the dependencies you need to
>   compile your project.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17773817/1009132):

> The `buildScript` block determines which plugins, task classes, and
>   other classes are available for use in the *rest of the build script*.
>   Without a `buildScript` block, you can use everything that ships with
>   Gradle out-of-the-box. If you additionally want to use third-party
>   plugins, task classes, or other classes (in the build script!), you
>   have to specify the corresponding dependencies in the `buildScript`
>   block.

As announced [here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/06/android-studio-30-canary-3-is-now.html):

> The Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0-alpha3 was also released through
>   maven.google.com.

So, try to fix it by adding Google’s Maven Repository.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Also add the repository here for other dependencies like the support libraries like [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html):

> Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with
>   the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

The difference is explained [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/what-is-difference-between-buildscript-classpath-and-dependencies-compile/4290)

> The "buildscript" block only controls dependencies for the buildscript
>   process itself, not for the application code, which the top-level
>   "dependencies" block controls.
>
> For instance, you could define dependencies in "buildscript/classpath"
>   that represent Gradle plugins used in the build process. Those plugins
>   would not be referenced as dependencies for the application code.

As commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44366452/1009132) by @lugegege, this version doesn't exist in Bintray JCenter:

> [com.android.tools.build.gradle](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle)
>   latest version is 2.5.0-alpha-preview-02, there is no 3.0.0-alpha3

Answer (score 1):

[com.android.tools.build.gradle](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle) latest version is 2.5.0-alpha-preview-02, there is no 3.0.0-alpha3

Answer (score 0):

Use this.. This may work because this worked in my case:

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'
}
```

and put this at the end of the app-level build.gradle file (after the dependencies).

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have no clue why putting this at the end (and not at the beginning ) solves the error.

Ok… So trying to put an end to all problems you guys have faced with my solution

This is my final app level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your-app-name"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
     }

   repositories {
    jcenter()
    }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6@aar'
}

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is my final project level gradle

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
   buildscript {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
     }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    }

   allprojects {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
   }
   }
```

Compare this with your own gradle files, and add or modify any values which are different from what I've written.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem this morning ! 
As Vishal said, there is no gradle-3.0.0-alpha3..
I am sure that, since I downloaded "Android studio 3.0 Canary (Alpha3)", I was on on the same version of gradle (3.0.0 alpha3), and it worked ! (Since today).

So I've put : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2' to compile.

EDIT : I have two versions of Android studio, When I used Android Studio 3.0, it changes gradle to gradle 3.0.0-alpha3 !

Answer (score -1):

write these gradles..

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.2'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

Comment: i am using the latest version what is the problem with it

Comment: Add this :  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

Comment: OP maybe wants using lambdas without retrolamda and he needs exactly that gradle version, why he should use old versions?