# Android O Gradle build fails with travis ci

Tags: android, travis-ci

I'm trying to use Travis CI for my Android Project but my Builds constantly failing but works on local build. I am using Android Studio Preview 3 and gradle 3 alpha 3.

I am getting this error below.

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3.

Here is my build [log](https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/240254942/log.txt?X-Amz-Expires=30&X-Amz-Date=20170607T073957Z&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJRYRXRSVGNKPKO5A/20170607/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=1e9906928b4321f6a2578c0255f94f558e04b70105119783ee40ca45f62c5a0f) 
My Travis Config [file](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a7029ed98a7fc52cc2bc08fd2e21a53c)

My Project gradle [file](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a3cfeb0db2225c6f62f7b5fd875f6316)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm getting an Access denied error to your build [log](https://s3.amazonaws.com/archive.travis-ci.org/jobs/240254942/log.txt?X-Amz-Expires=30&X-Amz-Date=20170607T073957Z&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJRYRXRSVGNKPKO5A/20170607/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=1e9906928b4321f6a2578c0255f94f558e04b70105119783ee40ca45f62c5a0f), and I didn't use it, but I'll try to answer you.

As announced [here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/06/android-studio-30-canary-3-is-now.html):

> The Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0-alpha3 was also released through
>   maven.google.com.

You can try to fix it by adding Google’s Maven Repository [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a3cfeb0db2225c6f62f7b5fd875f6316#file-build-gradle-L6) like [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

> Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with
>   the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

As commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44366452/1009132), this version doesn't exist in Bintray JCenter:

> [com.android.tools.build.gradle](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle)
>   latest version is 2.5.0-alpha-preview-02, there is no 3.0.0-alpha3

Also be sure to update build tools to the latest version as suggested in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44366261/1009132):

> Update your build tools from SDK manager

I add links to samples using the new `sdkmanager` command line [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42731625/1009132).

I would need a sample project reproducing the issue to check my suggestions.

Comment: I needed to also add the google's maven repo on the build script also as I have already it on allprojects

Comment: I added an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44418259/1009132) but it was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44071080/1009132).